# Doxygen: rtf document have strange strings in paragraph title

Tags: doxygen

This is the first time I write on this forum, but I always have used tackoverflow for my job, so I'm sure I'll find a solution for a strange problem appear using `doxygen` tool.

The RTF document is created without any warning or error, but when I open it, I note, in the paragraph title, some strange string like:

`File Index
{tc "File Index"}File List`

or

```
function name (opzionale)
{tc \l 2 "function name (opzionale)"}{xe "function name (opzionale)"}
```

and so on. I really don't know what are these strings and what do they mean...
Please, could anyone tell me what's going on ?
Regards

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (current is 1.8.8)? With which reader do you see the problem?

Comment: Hi,I'm using Doxygen v1.8.8 and as reader I use word 2013 to open the created rtf document

Comment: I tried with 1.8.8 and Word 2007, Libre Office 4.1.4.2 and Open Office 4.0.1 and could not reproduce the problem. Can you supply an example?

Comment: Could you please try with Office 2013 ? This problem gets out even with an empty file...

Comment: I'm not in the possession of Word 2013 so I can, unfortunately, not test it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with MS Word 2013.
After I tried to use Open Office and Libre office to save in different types and so on there is a very easy Solution in my case:

These Strings are **formatter signs!**
So if you turn the display from these signs **off**, you will have a normal text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is just a hidden text. You can remove them (hide them) directly from Microsoft Word like this:

- press Office Button
- Word Options
- Display
  and from group: "*Always show these formatting marks on the screen*" you have to **uncheck** the option **Hidden text**.

It worked on my side.